# <select> on iphone makes content scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, cordova

I have a fixed header in my mobile app (phoneGap).

works fine until I have scrolled down the page and click a select input. When I do this, the content/ page scrolls down as the iphones select pops up, including the fixed header.

How can I stop this? either stop the content scrolling or change the header on focus of the select to not move somehow?

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Afraid I don't follow. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: edited question, any clearer?